# iMac freezing on boot Apple logo

Tags: mojave

I have a 2017 iMac running the latest version of macOS Mojave. When restarting my machine it freezes on the Apple logo about a third of the way through the progress bar. Sometimes half of the logo and progress bar gets cut off when it freezes and sometimes it changes color and sometimes it changes the font size if I’m in verbose mode. Sometimes when it freezes the Apple logo will get shifted over to the right side of the screen and get cut off on the right side of the screen. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Could you check the site for similar questions? Please use proper tags to search. I am certain that such questions have been asked before. See [tour] to see how site works. :)

Comment: I'd be tempted to start in safe mode and see if that makes a difference (SHIFT while starting) if is OK then, I would reinstall the OS right over the top of what you already have. That will preserve your apps and data, as long as you don't first reformat the drive...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like graphics driver is switching to basic configuration. If you’re not using any external monitor or recently used safe mode which couldn’t revert back to normal boot.

Another guess is an unsupported kext which is installed by a faulty or unsupported app or a corrupted kext cache.

You can take following actions as troubleshooting tips. These are however not guaranteed to work for your situation.

1A) You can rebuld the kext cache.

```
// Open Terminal (/Applications/Utility/Terminal.app)

sudo kextcache -i /
paste the above line and press Enter (It will ask you for system password).
```

1B) Optionally you can download kext utility to rebuild the cache for you. (Not tested on Mojave)

[Download Kext Utility](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/140647-latest-kext-utility-macos-sierra-super-speed-edition/)

2A) You can repair permissions from Disk Utility. /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app

2B) Run First Aid. (It will repair disk permissions and also find common disk errors.

If it doesn’t solve the problem, try resetting the SMC and NVRAM. It will revert your computer to default configurations.

Comment: Would that explain why sometimes after trying multiple times to boot it will finally boot but then next time u reboot it does the same thing? I have tied resetting NVRAM and SMC and have tried reinstalling macOS from safe mode...still the same problem of trying to boot numerous times and finally getting lucky and having it boot. It sometimes takes 30 minutes to an hour of trying to boot though

Comment: If the os is unable to update the cache, it will evaluate all the kexts every time the system restarts. Have you tried to repair permissions and force update the kext cache?

Comment: I'm not sure entirely sure how to do that

Comment: Open Disk Utility App in /Applications/Utilities and run First Aid. It will not only repair permissions but also check for any errors.

Comment: Update, I was able to get the report on the boot issue...can't make much sense of it. I'm wondering about the panic in the first line...

Comment: panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7f9c986b91): "virtual bool IOAccelLegacyDisplayMachine::display_mode_did_change(uint32_t): vendor driver returns false"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOAcceleratorFamily_kexts/IOAcceleratorFamily-438.1.25/Kext2/IOAccelLegacyDisplayMachine.cpp:267
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address

Comment: I ran the First Aid and received no errors. I have reset the NVRAM and SMC and that didn't seem to help. I booted into safe mode and then reinstalled macOS overtop of the existing install and that allowed me to get it booted and see the error reporting, but it didn't seem to solve the problem as it took me a few times trying to boot to get it to actually boot even after the reinstall